# Fallback for css3 multiple background-images?

Tags: css, background, background-image

I've got 2 images as background of my body:

```
background: url(../img/upper_bg.png) 0 495px repeat-x, url(../img/bg.png) repeat;
```

I found out that in order to show `upper_bg.png` above `bg.png` image I needed to place it first in the list. However for browsers that don't support multiple backgrounds I'd like to show just `bg.png`, I'm concerned that browser falls to `upper_bg.png` as a fallback instead of `bg.png`. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Simply adding a `background` declaration with just bg.png before the multiple backgrounds should do it:

```
background: url(../img/bg.png) repeat;
background: url(../img/upper_bg.png) 0 495px repeat-x, url(../img/bg.png) repeat;
```

Older browsers will ignore the second line and keep the first line; they shouldn't attempt to use any part of the second line at all. Browsers that do support multiple backgrounds will use the second line instead of the first by overriding it as normal.

Comment: Could this work for fallback images where the image is unavailable?  (e.g. profile images with a fallback silhouette, though using 404s during regular processing probably isn't canon)

Comment: Would there be an extra request if we had a different image for the fallback?

Comment: @rookie1024: Unfortunately, no. IIRC there is a different proposal for providing fallbacks in case of unreachable images - which would require a different syntax that doesn't rely on cascading, since cascading is a different concept entirely.

Comment: @nickspiel: The browser only requests the image(s) that it ends up using. So in my answer, if the browser supports multiple images it will not request bg.png a second time.

Comment: The multiple background image support is surprisingly good, even IE9 supports it! http://caniuse.com/#search=multiple%20background